# UIDatePicker and a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uidatepicker

I have a `UITableViewController` that is the detail view for another `UITableViewController`.

On this table is a cell labeled "Date". Using Apple's "DateCell" example (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html), I have tried to add a `UIDatePicker` when you touch the cell.

I have wired up everything exactly the way the example does. The only thing I've changed is that I fenced the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` code in this:

```
if(indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0)
{
   //Date picker stuff
}
```

This is to ensure it only runs when the right cell is pressed.

For the life of me, I can't get it to work. Clicking it does nothing but turn it blue (selected). Clicking it repeatedly does nothing.

If I scroll to the bottom of the UITableView, clicking it animates up a white rectangle. Clicking repeatedly eventually covers the whole table view.

It doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Please..how can I do this?

If you want more code, I can provide it, but it's virtually identical to the DateCell code. I copied/pasted for the most part.

Thanks in advance,

Clif

Comment: Nobody will download the dateCell example just to answer your question, not even me. So replace `//Date picker stuff` with real code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you have a picker object in IB if that's what you are using, then create an IBOutlet reference and connect it to the IB object. I set my pickerView to hidden in IB and make it visible when required. Otherwise you can simply instantiate one as needed.

In your didSelectRowAtIndexPath, you can try the code below and see what happens.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (**your cell/section selection logic here**) {
        [self.view endEditing:YES]; // resign firstResponder if you have any text fields so the keyboard doesn't get in the way
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES]; // Scroll your row to the top so the user can actually see the row when interacting with the pickerView

        // Pickerview setup
        [self.typePicker setCenter:CGPointMake(150, 500)]; // place the pickerView outside the screen boundaries
        [self.typePicker setHidden:NO]; // set it to visible and then animate it to slide up
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"slideIn" context:nil];
        [self.typePicker setCenter:CGPointMake(150, 250)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];        
    }
}
```

After that you need to implement your `pickerView:didSelectRow:` method if you want to update the label of your cell as the picker view selection changes...

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
    // Your code to get the current table view cell and update it with the data from your pickerView
}
```

Make sure your viewController is declared as delegate for the tableView `<UITableViewDelegate>` as well as for the pickerView `'

This should give you a good head start. Let me know if you have any questions etc.

Cheers,
Rog

Comment: Well, this is why I shouldn't post on StackOverflow late at night.  I realized that the reason I'm having an issue is because I never added the UIDatePicker to my window and connected the outlets.  This being my first iPhone app, up until this point I've instantiated most objects in code. I just need to do the same for this one. Your comment triggered this realization, so I'm giving you credit.  Sorry for wasting your time.